# How to handle timeouts with php5-fpm + nginx timeout php.ini

Tags: php, timeout, fastcgi

how to handle timeouts with PHP in php5-fpm + ngnix configurations?

I tried to make a simple script with just

```
sleep(60);
```

php.ini

```
max_execution_time = 30
```

fast_cgi

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
fastcgi_send_timeout 50;
fastcgi_read_timeout 50;
```

The script stops at 50s for timeout of the backend. What do I have to do to

1. enable the max_execution_time in php.ini
2. enable ini_set to change the execution time to 0 directly in the
   script

Why does fast_cgi get to control timeouts over everything instead of php itself?

Comment: Does FastCGI load the `php.ini` configuration file? Does it have its own?

Comment: it seems it does load it because if I change values they show in phpinfo(), it just ignores max_execution_time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was basically the fact that on Linux the timeout counts only for the actual "php work" and not for all stream function times and moreover not for `sleep` that's why I never reached the limit and fastgci timeout always kicked in. Instead on Windows the actual "human" time elapsed counts.

from the PHP doc:

> The set_time_limit() function and the configuration directive
>   max_execution_time only affect the execution time of the script
>   itself. Any time spent on activity that happens outside the execution
>   of the script such as system calls using system(), stream operations,
>   database queries, etc. is not included when determining the maximum
>   time that the script has been running. This is not true on Windows
>   where the measured time is real.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your PHP code.

Comment: i tried that but it has no effect, fast_cgi is still controlling everything

Answer (score 0):

When use `php-cgi(php-fpm)`  php.ini's `max_execution_time`will not take effects, but 
fpm configuration item `request_terminate_timeout` will handle script execution time .

In php-fpm.conf set this item like below:

```
request_terminate_timeout = 60s
```